# Invalid set index 'texture', in GDScript?

Tags: 2d, godot, gdscript

**I keep getting an error, when I try to run a function from a different script.**

**Script 1**:

```
extends Node2D

var tex = preload("res://icon.svg")
@onready var sprite = $Char/Person

func create_person():
    sprite.texture = tex
```

**Script 2**:

```
extends Node2D

var script_1 = preload("res://Script_1.gd").new()

func _ready():
    script_1.create_person()
```

**Error**:`Invalid set index 'texture' (on base: 'Nil') with value of type 'CompressedTexture2D'`

Ive asked ChatGPT, and have troubleshooted the issue elsewhere. I need the script to load in the texture on that sprite when script 2 calls the function create_person().

Answer (score 0):

You've preloaded script_1.gd and created a new instance of the class, and stored that into your variable script_1, however you won't be able to access any of the nodes in that class as you would need to preload/load it as an instance of a scene to do this. You would then need to add that scene into the scene tree before you can access the sprite within that class. Something like this:

```
var script_1: PackedScene = preload("res://Script_1.gd")
```

or if you're only going to ever want one instance of this Scene you could just do this:

```
var script_1: Node2D = preload("res://Script_1.gd").instance()
```

Then inside your Script_2 ready function, you want to do this:

```
add_child(script_1)
script_1.create_person()
```

That should work.